# How can I close parent div function when I clicked child div and when I clicked parent div again, the function will activity

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick

I want to let user go to some website when he clicked my website background picture(parent div), but the function need be closed when user clicked my website content(child div), and then when user clicked the background picture(parent div) again, the function will be activity.

I try many times, but when I clicked my website content(child div), and clicked website background picture(parent div) again, the function didn't work.

What can I do? Thank you!

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"></meta>
        <title>Test!</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .head{
                background-color:#FF88C2; color:#9955FF; font-weight:bold; font-size:30px;
                text-align:center; padding:10px;
        }

        .tt{
               width:100%; height:100%;
               border:1px solid red;
        }

        .content{
                width:800px; height:1000px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; background-color: aliceblue;
                border:1px solid blue;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function bgADlink(){
            window.open('https://www.google.com');
        }

        var i = 0;

        function test1(){
            if(i == 0 || i == 1)
                bgADlink();

            return i = 0;
        }

        function test2(){
            bgADlink=false;

            return i = 1;
        }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body style="margin:0px; background-color:#eeeeee;">
        <div class="head">Test</div>
        <div class="tt" onclick="test1()">
            <div class="content" onclick="test2()"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello, so what do you mean by " but the function need be closed" ? Disabled? What is parent div ? Body element or some inner div? In example code you don't have any parent and child divs. Can you exactly say which div must have that onclick action?

Comment: @maximelian1986  `you don't have any parent and child divs`  There is the div with class `tt` (parent), and class `content` (child).  But I think the OP really needs to re-word his question as it's very confusing what's wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just remove that || i == 1 condition from test1() function like below.

```
function test1(){
    if(i == 0)
        bgADlink();

    return i = 0;
}
```

check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ca7Lbsy3/

Answer (score 0):

There are different problems in your code.

Because events propagate from an inner element, to it's parent element (not only parent but all the hierarchy up), the "tt" div will always fire, so the best thing to do is to stop the propagation of the events with

```
onclick="event.stopPropagation();test1()"
```

I don't really understand what you're trying to accomplish with the "i" and why your having a function bgADlink() and then assigning it a Boolean, JavaScript lets you do that, but basically your function is now a Boolean.

I made you a small sample fiddler yo you can see the stopPropagation working, hope it helps.

https://jsfiddle.net/pimboden40/kg9wfdqj/29/

Answer (score 0):

this snippet is not opening parent div link either..but use this on html page then try it

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"></meta>
        <title>Test!</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .head{
                background-color:#FF88C2; color:#9955FF; font-weight:bold; font-size:30px;
                text-align:center; padding:10px;
        }

        .tt{
               width:100%; height:100%;
               border:1px solid red;
        }

        .content{
                width:800px; height:1000px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; background-color: aliceblue;
                border:1px solid blue;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       

        var i = 0;

        function test1(){
            if(i == 0 || i == 1)
                bgADlink();

            return i = 0;
        }

        function test2(varr,event){
            // bgADlink=false;
             event.stopPropagation();
            return i = 1;
        }
         function bgADlink(){
          console.log("bgADlink")
            window.open('https://www.google.com');
        }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body style="margin:0px; background-color:#eeeeee;">
        <div class="head">Test</div>
        <div class="tt" onclick="test1()">
            <div class="content" onclick="test2('',event)"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that is what you need, but basically you need to stop event bubbling from child to parent.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8"></meta>
            <title>Test!</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            .head{
                    background-color:#FF88C2; color:#9955FF; font-weight:bold; font-size:30px;
                    text-align:center; padding:10px;
            }

            .tt{
                   width:100%; height:100%;
                   border:1px solid red;
            }

            .content{
                    width:800px; height:1000px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; background-color: aliceblue;
                    border:1px solid blue;
            }
        </style>
        <script
            src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
              integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
              crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function bgADlink(){
                window.open('https://www.google.com');
            }

            $(document).ready(function(){
             $(".tt").on("click",function(){
               bgADlink();
              });

              $(".content").on("click",function(e){
               e.stopPropagation();
              });
            });
        </script>
        </head>
        <body style="margin:0px; background-color:#eeeeee;">
            <div class="head">Test</div>
            <div class="tt" onclick="test1()">
                <div class="content" onclick="test2()"></div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```